# How to include specific lines from latex file for org-export

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I am writing a text in orgmode that I want to export to pdf. I want to include specific lines from a latex file using `#+include:`. In fact, I want to include multiple text sections from a single latex file at specific locations in an org file.

Following the [documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Include-Files.html) I should be able to do so using the `:lines` argument with `export latex`. This, however, seems not to be working.

An org file with the following content:

```
#+TITLE: Some File

* Heading

#+include: "another-file.tex" export latex :lines 3-5
```

Does not include anything from the latex file.

I also tested whether the order of arguments had an effect, i.e., with `#+include: "another-file.tex" :lines 3-5 export latex`. This results in the whole .tex-file being included in the exported PDF.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please submit a bug report with `M-x org-submit-bug-report`. I don't think you are missing anything.

Comment: Thanks @NickD, I'll file one, and thanks also for bringing that command to my attention.

Comment: As the answer points out, it's more of a documentation bug than anything else. OTOH, it's not clear to me that the quotes buy us anything, so it may still be worth asking on the ML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your code and when I add quotation marks to the line numbers (as described in the documentation), it works.

Here is the working code:

```
#+TITLE: Some File

* Heading

#+include: "another-file.tex" export latex :lines "3-5"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are right: the regexp for lines is looking for the quotes. But the documentation is inconsistent: section `Include file` has four examples. the first three with quotes, the fourth without.